Black and white war movie with a locomotive and sabotage
It's a war-time movie, filmed in black and white. There's a rail yard, and the "General's" pipe gets stuck down in the floor, to where the tracks control lever wouldn't move, and a train almost crashes because of it. There's a big, stocky man who drives a steam locomotive wrecklessely. When the big, stocky man spits in the General's face, two guys take him behind a wall and shot him, as the good guy is trying to convince the General to spare him, since the big guy saved him. The General has the good guy go into, perhaps a hotel, to get some sleep, so the good guy doesn't fall asleep behind the controls of the train that he's going to drive.
The good guy sneaks out of the hotel and blows up a jeep by lighting a rag at the gas tank, then sneaks back into the Hotel. The woman who owns the hotel sees him sneaking back. When the General goes into the hotel to check on the good guy, the good guy is found in the kitchen eating at the table.
The General asks the woman who owns the hotel, "How long has he been sitting there?" She looks at the good guy, then looks at the General and lies to him by saying, "Since soup, (pause) since meatloaf, (pause) since chicken. Then it seams like they fall for each other before he leaves. Then, the good guy tells the General the next morning, "Like a baby" when the General asked how he slept.

Year? B&W as in pre-color, or intentional?

I thinks in pre-color. Thanks, Jsaon.

Sorry. I'm not sure of the year, but I think it's in pre-color. Thanks Jason.

This is John Frankenheimer's The Train from 1964 with Burt Lancaster and Jeanne Moreau.

Oberst von Waldheim wants to bring modern paintings, the ones the Nazis called "degenerate", out of Paris before the Allied Forces liberate Paris. He is able to persuade his bosses to give him the train. Labiche, a French railway official is asked by the management of the museum to stop this train, but he is not willing to risk the life of his people for art. But when his old friend Boule is shot by the Germans accusing him for sabotage on the engine he starts to work against the Germans, and tries to delay the departure of the train until the Allies are arriving.

All the scenes you mentioned are there. Well remembered. Here's the trailer:



